# Testcafe scripts mostly fails over Mozilla Firefox browser due page load issue

Tags: javascript, testing, firefox, automated-tests, testcafe

The page is very slow to load when run via TestCafe over Firefox. If I manually load the page in the browser, the page loads reasonably fast. So I'm not sure what's causing the page to load slowly. Even while executing basic testcafe scripts in Firefox we can easily observe this Slowness issue. We have a longer Script execution time because of this issue. If the same script is executed over the chrome browser we are not facing a page load issue and script execution time is almost half as compared to chrome.

To quantify the number of scripts passed ratio in chrome is 70-75% but in Firefox it's hardly around 20-25%. I'm not sure what causes this issue.

Any help or suggestion will be much appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

**Sample Code :**

```
import { Role } from "testcafe";
import { Selector } from "testcafe";

fixture`FirefoxSlowness`.beforeEach(async t => {
    await t.wait(8000)
    await t.navigateTo("https://dxc.com/us/en");
    await t.maximizeWindow();
});

test('DXCTestWebsite_Test_01', async t => {
    const Logo = Selector('#Logo_and_Copy').exists;
    await t.expect(Logo).ok();
    await t.click('[class="nav-link mega-menu-toggle collapsed"]');
    await t.wait(1000)
    await t.click('#onetrust-accept-btn-handler')
    await t.click('[class="mega-menu__nav-item nav-item"]')
    await t.click('[class="card-link"]')
    await t.click('#contact-us-link')
    const contactus = Selector('[class="cmp-accordion__title"]')
    await t.click(contactus.withExactText("Careers"))
    await t.wait(2000)
    await t.click('[href="/us/en/careers"]')
    await t.click('#typehead')
    await t.typeText('#typehead', '42A - Human Resources Specialist')
    await t.click('#ph-search-backdrop')
    await t.click('[data-ph-id="ph-page-element-page24-AA0w8h"]')
});
```

Comment: Could you please share a simple example so that I can reproduce the issue locally?

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have shared a simple code example in the question under sample code (pls have a look at the top) that we execute through Firefox. when we execute it through firefox page doesn't load and due to the testcafe is not able to find the locator so test fails there. but manually and through chrome we don't face page load issues. Please guide us on what could be the reason for this issue.

Comment: I'm sorry, but the example you gave is unreadable and irreproducible. Please fix it so I can use it.

Comment: We won't be able send code for our application because of organizations policy. but please allow me some time i will check what example i can share.

Comment: Thank you for the patience. I have updated our organization code in the code. Please check the question.

Comment: we have executed the same code for 2 browsers Chrome and Firefox.
Time Taken by browsers are mentioned below.
Chrome :- 3 min 35 sec
Firefox  :-  4 min 43 sec

Comment: I ran your example on firefox 5 times without any flash and got only the `JavaScript error` error on step `await t.click('#typehead')`. Also, I ran it with `--skip-js-errors` options over 10 times. I didn't get any errors during the loading page. Also, I mentioned that all tests were completed approximately in 30s. Please let me know whether you run the test on the local machine on remote and which options or config you use.

Comment: we usually face page loading issue for long script or executing n number of scripts through batch file. To test the same i wrote the above-mentioned code in 4 different test. To answer your question, we have executed it through local machine. Apart from that i have one question why browsers are taking different time to execute the same code?

Comment: Since different browsers have different engines, they work in different ways and have different performance. Does only the test mentioned above take 3-4 minutes? If you have a low-performance machine, can you reproduce the issue on another one? Try to run tests with the [`cache`](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402638/reference/configuration-file?search#cache) option. Also, please describe all steps you take to run tests.

Comment: No, the above-mentioned test takes only 30 sec to execute but we face load issues with large scripts to check that, in TestScript we wrote the above test 4 times. we use High-performance AWS m/c to execute our script(large scripts execute perfectly in chrome but in Firefox we face difficulties while executing).  There are no special steps we follow. Before executing the tests we simply clear the cache of both browsers(Manually) and created batches (batches contain commands to execute multiple testscripts Ex. testcafe chrome/Firefox test.js -e) we double-click on it to execute.

Comment: I run this test 15 times in a loop and I didn't get the error you described. Please create an example that can be easily reproduced. You can share your test [here](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=TYPE%3A+bug&template=bug_report.yaml) if you don't want to send it in this thread.